Calling "No Trump" as trump in Euchre
I come from a long line of Euchre players.  When all players have turned down ordering up trump and it goes to each player to name a suit, we have also included "No Trump" as an option. Meaning if you have, for example: A,K,Q of the same suit, or A,K, of one suit and A of another suit, or some other variation of high suit cards, you can name No Trump and be guaranteed taking 3 tricks.  We have played that way for a long time but I can't find any online information on it.  Does anyone else play this way too?

No Trump is not a valid bid in official Euchre.  But it is valid in some variants.
For example, the Pepper variant allows no trump bids.

Pepper is a variant of bid Euchre that is popular in Iowa and Southern Minnesota.

For official Euchre rules, see for example Pagat, Wikipedia, cardgames.io and worldofcardgames.
